# Multi language support in android

Tags: android, multilingual

I want to display UI text in multilanguage, I have done multi-language support for defined no.of lanugauges in the resource subdirectories and string resource files. For example:

MyProject/

```
res/
   values/
       strings.xml
   values-es/
       strings.xml
   values-fr/
       strings.xml
```

**Problem 1:** 
    I want to support multilanguage for **undefined no.of languages**, which mean that admin can change lanugage dynamically in the backend.

I have following solutions too:

**Soultion 1:**
I can pull supported langugae string from server and store it in db but in this case My app perfomance might slow.

**Soultion 2:**
I can pull supported langugae string from server and store it in resource directory with respected language directory. In this case android system doesn't allow to write file in res directory at runtime.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: solution 1. you cannot store it in `res` folder in `Runtime`

Comment: What about extension APKs for languages?

Comment: @shkschneider Can't understand

Comment: You can store it in Shared Preference for later use instead of xml string.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Solution 1 would be better for your dynamic multi-language support. And expansion apks (not extension apk ;) ) means your apk would get this language data from server after installed into user's device. Like, we can see this most video games which has more assets data. refer for that. http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: You should load the string to a custom class at startup from a db and read the eg Hashmap <string key, string language_string> from there. Don't do a query on every string you need, just load it on startup

Comment: @kibzorg How you feel app performance and other things about solution 1? and I don't like to go with expansion apks in my case.

Comment: @Sathish For your problem, I got one solution that you have to try is, create a file that contain you app's language in key,value pair format and save this into you app's data directory.
Do this for all language which you want to support and maintain list of supported languages. 

Now ,when you want to add new language just save new file to directory and edit you languages list.